# Renaming files to folder names

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I currently have a script I have been working on for a few hours and having some trouble. What it does is takes all .dat files in the C:\TEST\WF\ directory and renames it to the folder name plus .txt. However it is not renaming the files to the folder name, it grabs the previous folder instead

Example:

Source Directory:

1. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER1\FILE.dat
2. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER2\FILE.dat
3. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER3\FILE.dat

Current output:

1. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER1\WF.txt
2. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER2\WF.txt
3. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER3\WF.txt

Expected output

1. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER1\FOLDER1.txt
2. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER2\FOLDER2.txt
3. C:\TEST\WF\FOLDER3\FOLDER3.txt

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /d %%F in (C:\TEST\WF\*) do (
       for %%* in (%%F) do set CurrDirName=%%*
       IF EXIST "%%F\*.dat" (REN "%%F\*.dat" %CurrDirName%.txt)
       )
   ```

Comment: [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). But why don't you use just `%%~n*` instead of a needless variable?

Comment: Stephan, Thank you so much.